# Did Lincoln say, "When we buy steel made in America, we get the steel and the money too"?

Tags: economics, quotes

In "Industrial Policy Comes Full Circle" (Dec. 15), Clyde Prestowitz (*Wall Street Journal*, [2022-12-11](https://www.wsj.com/articles/free-trade-united-states-policy-11670602596), 2022-22-15 print edition p. R17):

> Lincoln said: "I don't know much about tariffs, but I do know that when we buy steel abroad, the foreigner gets the money and we get the steel, but when we buy steel made in America, we get the steel and the money too."

Did Lincoln say the above?

Comment: obvious point: mass steel manufacture wasn't really a thing until after Lincoln was dead. Bessimer didn't really gt rolling until c. 1870

Comment: If "getting the money" means "keeping the money" I think he was right, but (at least ideally) to spend the money you got to have it first. So if Americans buy in America, the amount of money won't change (likewise for the steel mined in America).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### No.

From Frank Taussig ([1914](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1885656)), "Abraham Lincoln on the Tariff: A Myth":

> It seems certain that the phrase is apocryphal. There is no evidence that Lincoln ever used it. ... By dint of repetition it has come to be associated with Lincoln almost as much as the cherry tree is associated with Washington. So crude is the reasoning (if such it can be called), so vulgarly fallacious is the antithesis, that we must hope that it will cease to be invested with the sanction of a venerated name.

A bit more from Taussig:

> The very first mention which we have found is in 1894, in the *American Economist*, a weekly protectionist sheet published in New York ...:

> "Lincoln's first speech on the tariff question was short and to the point. He said he did not pretend to be learned in political economy, but he thought that he knew enough to know that 'when an American paid twenty dollars for steel to an English manufacturer, America had the steel and England had the twenty dollars. But when he paid twenty dollars for the steel to an American manufacturer, America had both the steel and the twenty dollars.'" ...

> the phrase was not current before 1894 ...

> But after 1900 it turns up repeatedly ...

> After the very first appearance, the commodity mentioned seems to be invariably rails, — sometimes iron rails, sometimes steel rails. ...

> The first appearance for express campaign use appears to be in 1904. ... In the Campaign Book of 1904, there is an extended quotation from Lincoln's tariff notes of 1846-47 (referred to a moment ago) and then at the close we find: -

> "On another occasion Mr. Lincoln is quoted as saying: 'I am not posted on the tariff, but I know that if I give my wife twenty dollars to buy a cloak and she buys one made in free-trade England, we have the cloak, but England has the twenty dollars; while if she buys a cloak made in the protected United States, we have the cloak and the twenty dollars.'"

Etc.

---

In the century-plus since Taussig (1914), this nonsensical "Lincoln quote" has been repeated many more times (usually with some slight alterations), usually by those with a poor understanding of economics (and hence for whom the quote has appeal), and most recently in late 2022 by Clyde Prestowitz in the *Wall Street Journal*. (Today if you Google "lincoln tariff quote", Taussig (1914) appears as the first result. So it's quite amazing that the "quote" is still being repeated as fact.)

Comment: The first attribution to Lincoln might have been 1894, but the 1885 book Graab says "if we buy £ 1000 worth of goods from abroad , the foreigner gets the money - or the money's worth , in some shape or form - and the foreign workman gets the work he wages ; while if the articles are produced in England , we have the goods , we have the work , and we keep the money too ." https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gra%C3%A4b/xld0raAaCZAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22foreign+workman+gets+the+work+and+%22+%22money+too%22&pg=PA95&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @DavePhD: Thanks good find. I'm sure we can find many more variants of this fallacy if we continue going back centuries (and also in future centuries). It gains special significance when attributed to Lincoln (whom many Americans regard as a sacred authority and whose "quotes" they are happy to repeat, provided they agree with the quote).

Comment: But whether he said these particular words or not, Lincoln certainly backed tariffs so that seems moot.

Comment: "*So crude is the reasoning (if such it can be called), so vulgarly fallacious is the antithesis, that …*" — what exactly *is* the fallacy?

Comment: @RayButterworth IMO, the fallacy is the omission of the counterbalancing facts that when buying from abroad, we *don't use up our own steel* (i.e., we gain the steel we bought *without diminution* of our existing supply of steel or its input materials), and the workers who *would have* made/processed the steel domestically will instead have time and energy to do *something else* productive that they couldn't have otherwise.

Comment: @RayButterworth: Ask the Q at Econ or elsewhere. But consider this quote that I assure you is also by Lincoln: *when I buy a car from a stranger outside my household, the stranger gets the money and I get the car, but when I buy a car made by my wife, we get the car and the money too.*

Comment: Sounds like the quote is good paraphrase of lincoln's view.

Comment: @paulj And Adam Smith's view as well.  It's frequently conveniently omitted from discussion of the idea these days, but Smith's famous "invisible hand" came specifically from a discussion about the benefits of keeping the scope of your economy local when possible and "preferring the support of domestic to that of foreign industry."

Comment: Shouldn't this be 'Yes, but not exactly as quoted'? This seems like almost exactly what he wrote.

Comment: I think the point is that the phrase first showed up in 1894, almost 30 years after Lincoln's death. And it's very, very similar to that similar quote from someone in England, 1885, mentioned by @DavePhD.

Answer (score 20):

This was debunked in 1914 by [Abraham Lincoln on the Tariff: A Myth](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1885656#metadata_info_tab_contents) *The Quarterly Journal of Economics* Vol. 28, No. 4 (Aug., 1914), pp. 814-820:

> THOSE who have followed the campaign literature on the
> tariff during recent years will have become familiar with a
> phrase attributed to Abraham Lincoln. The following version is taken from Curtiss's Industrial Development of Nations
> (1912), a pretentious three-volume publication, in which are
> collected indiscriminately all sorts of protectionist arguments.
> Under a portrait of Lincoln this is printed: -
> " I do not know much about the tariff, but I know this much, when
> we buy manufactured goods abroad, we get the goods and the
> foreigner gets the money. When we buy the manufactured goods at
> home, we get both the goods and the money.
> No reference is given by Curtiss to Lincoln's writings; nor
> is such a reference given in any place where I have found the
> phrase quoted. A careful examination of the various editions
> of Lincoln's published works brings to light nothing that
> remotely resembles it. There is nothing in either of the two
> editions of his writings put together by Nicolay and Hay, nor
> is there anything in the so called Federal Edition. Nicolay and
> Hay's Life yields nothing of the sort, nor any of the biographies.
> So with Lincoln's Speeches in Congress and his Messages to
> Congress. There is no lack, to be sure, of references to the
> tariff by Lincoln. He began his political career as a Whig,
> and remained a protectionist; tho during the decade preceding the war his political insight led him to put it aside as an
> issue on which to appeal to the people. Those who are interested in the history of the. tariff controversy may find it
> worth while to turn to some notes of his, written in 1846-67,
> containing a sketch of an address on the tariff. Here the
> main thought is that labor given to transporting a commodity
> from foreign countries is wasted, if the commodity can be
> produced within the country with as little labor as elsewhere.'
> This may be an echo of some of Carey's well-known utterances; and it could be made the text for some explanation of the principle of comparative cost. A passage of a similar sort is in an address made at **Pittsburg in 1861**, indicating that Lincoln had kept this particular turn of reasoning in mind.
> But there is not the slightest suggestion of the much-quoted
> phrase.

In the actual [15 February 1861 speech](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/l/lincoln/lincoln4/1:330?rgn=div1;view=fulltext) Lincoln says concerning tariffs:

> it seems a fitting time to indulge in a few remarks upon **the important question of a tariff**---a subject of great magnitude, and one which is attended with many difficulties, owing to the great variety of interests which it involves. So long as direct taxation for the support of government is not resorted to, a tariff is necessary. The tariff is to the government what a meal is to the family; but, while this is admitted, it still becomes necessary to modify and change its operations according to new interests and new circumstances. So far there is little difference of opinion among politicians, but the question as to how far imposts may be adjusted for the protection of home industry, gives rise to various views and objections. **I must confess that I do not understand this subject in all its multiform bearings**, but I promise you that I will give it my closest attention, and endeavor to comprehend it more fully. And here I may remark that the Chicago platform contains a plank upon this subject, which I think should be regarded as law for the incoming administration. In fact, this question, as well as all other subjects embodied in that platform, should not be varied from what we gave the people to understand would be our policy when we obtained their votes. Permit me, fellow citizens, to read the tariff plank of the Chicago platform, or rather, to have it read in your hearing by one who has younger eyes than I have.

> Mr. Lincoln's private Secretary then read section twelfth of the Chicago platform, as follows:

> That, while providing revenue for the support of the General Government by duties upon imposts, sound policy requires such an adjustment of the imposts as to encourage the development of the industrial interest of the whole country, and we commend that policy of national exchanges which secures to the working men liberal wages, to agriculture remunerating prices, to mechanics and manufacturers an adequate reward for their skill, labor and enterprise, and to the nation commercial prosperity and independence.

> Mr. Lincoln continued---Now, fellow-citizens, I must confess that there are shades of difference in construing even this plank of the platform. But I am not now intending to discuss these differences, but merely to give you some general ideas upon this subject. I have long thought that if there be any article of necessity which can be produced at home with as little or nearly the same labor as abroad, it would be better to protect that article. Labor is the true standard of value. **If a bar of iron, got out of the mines of England, and a bar of iron taken from the mines of Pennsylvania, be produced at the same cost, it follows that if the English bar be shipped from Manchester to Pittsburg, and the American bar from Pittsburg to Manchester, the cost of carriage is appreciably lost. [Laughter.] If we had no iron here, then we should encourage its shipment from foreign countries; but not when we can make it as cheaply in our own country. This brings us back to our first proposition, that if any article can be produced at home with nearly the same cost as abroad, the carriage is lost labor.**

> The treasury of the nation is in such a low condition at present that this subject now demands the attention of Congress, and will demand the immediate consideration of the new Administration. The tariff bill now before Congress may or may not pass at the present session. I confess I do not understand the precise provisions of this bill, and I do not know whether it can be passed by the present Congress or not. It may or may not become the law of the land---but if it does, that will be an end of the matter until a modification can be effected, should it be deemed necessary. If it does not pass (and the latest advices I have are to the effect that it is still pending) the next Congress will have to give it their earliest attention.

> According to my political education, I am inclined to believe that the people in the various sections of the country should have their own views carried out through their representatives in Congress, and if the consideration of the Tariff bill should be postponed until the next session of the National Legislature, no subject should engage your representatives more closely than that of a tariff. And if I have any recommendation to make, it will be that every man who is called upon to serve the people in a representative capacity, should study this whole subject thoroughly, as I intend to do myself, looking to all the varied interests of our common country, so that when the time for action arrives adequate protection can be extended to the coal and iron of Pennsylvania, the corn of Illinois, and the ``reapers of Chicago.'' Permit me to express the hope that this important subject may receive such consideration at the hands of your representatives, that the interests of no part of the country may be overlooked, but that all sections may share in common the benefits of a just and equitable tariff.

In addition to what Lincoln actually said at the Pittsburg speech, there is the [manuscript](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/l/lincoln/lincoln4/1:330?rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=tariff) he wrote for the speech, which is somewhat different, relevantly including:

> I have, by no means, a thoroughly matured judgment upon this subject---especially as to details. Some general ideas are about all. I have long thought that to produce any necessary article at home, which can be made of as good quality, and with as little labor at home as abroad, would better be made at home, at least by the difference of the carrying from abroad. In such case, the carrying is demonstrably a dead loss of labor. For instance, labor being the true standard of value, is it not plain, that **if equal labor get a bar of rail-road iron out of a mine in England, and another out of a mine in Pennsylvania, each can be laid down in a track at home, cheaper than they could exchange countries, at least by the cost of carriage**. If there be a present cause why one can be both made and carried, cheaper, in money price, than the other can be made without carrying, that cause is an unnatural, and injurious one, and ought, gradually, if not rapidly, to be removed.

Two follow-up articles to the 1914 debunking article were published.

In [Lincoln and the Tariff: A Sequel](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1884970?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) *The Quarterly Journal of Economics* Vol. 29, No. 2 (Feb., 1915), pp. 426-429 it is realized that the quote was first attributed to Lincoln in a 9 June 1894 issue of the newspaper *Harvard Independent*.  It is concluded that oration about Lincoln by Robert G. Ingersoll containing the quote was confused by Harvard Independent as being an actual Lincoln quote, and example of which is on [page 128](https://archive.org/details/worksofrobertgin03ingeiala/page/128/mode/2up) of volume 3 of Works of Robert G. Ingersoll.

In [The Lincoln Tariff Myth Finally Disposed of](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1884100#metadata_info_tab_contents) *The Quarterly Journal of Economics* Vol. 35, No. 3 (May, 1921), p. 500 evidence that Robert G. Ingersoll was using the quote starting about 1880 is presented and it is concluded that attribution to Lincoln was accidental.

Comment: "Under a portrait of Lincoln this is printed: ..." – in other words, they'd already invented the Image Quote meme in 1912.

Comment: The bolded passage ending with **the carriage is lost labor** commits no fallacy and is in no way similar to the fallacy in the "quotes" falsely attributed to Lincoln. Today we would more simply say that the transport costs are lost/wasted. (So I'm not sure what purpose the addition of these paragraphs serves other than further confusion and perhaps a false suggestion that Lincoln ever said something similar.)

Comment: But Lincoln does seem to commit the separate and unrelated fallacy that economists today usually refer to as the Labor Theory of Value (LTV) when he states, "Labor is the true standard of value," and, "labor being the true standard of value". (The LTV was also subscribed to by Adam Smith, David Ricardo, Marx, and many other great economists. It was only cleared up from the 1870s, though as usual some form of it often continues to be circulated in confused form.)

Comment: @user24096 yes, I have the vinyl Red Shadow album "Better Red" with the song "Labor is Value" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NSxgbAW1Hw

Comment: @user24096 "commits no fallacy" is questionable (broken window); the passage is nonetheless wrong: the cost is not merely the purchase price or the labor to produce the iron, the cost is that which is foregone to get the iron. Relative advantages mean that it is almost certainly "better" (meaning globally and nationally advantageous) to produce the iron one place or the other and ship it.

Comment: @fectin: I understand the two long bold passages to mean simply this: If it costs $100 to produce a bar of iron in either America or England but the cost of transport from England to America is another $10, then we Americans should just produce the iron in America. To me there is no fallacy in this. If you have a different understanding of those passages, please explain (I have no idea what your parenthetical "broken window" means).

Comment: @user24096 I'm not going to explain comparative advantage and broken window fallacy in a comment on something unrelated. Here's an easy google result: http://www2.york.psu.edu/~dxl31/econ14/lecture27.html

Comment: @fectin: Comparative advantage is about when we produce two or more goods. Here we've assumed an equal cost of $100 for a single good (a bar of iron) across both countries and the question is merely whether we (in America) want to (a) pay $100 for the iron produced in America; or (b) pay $100 for the iron produced in England. So comparative advantage is irrelevant here. Lincoln is saying (correctly) that if there are no additional transport costs, then it doesn't matter whether we choose (a) or (b). But if there's an additional $10 in transport costs for (b), then we should choose (a).

Comment: @fectin: What is the "broken window" here? In economics, the "broken window" fallacy usually refers to Bastiat. But what is Lincoln asking to be deliberately broken here to be fixed?